# SVG Pixel Compositing Operations in NumPy

Tags: numpy, gimp, array-broadcasting, svg-filters

I am using GIMP layer operations which (AFAICT) map back to SVG Compositing operations (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/-/blob/master/operations/generated/src.c, https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGCompositing)

I am working with images loaded by OpenCV, and manipulated with NumPy. I am most interested in implementing the GIMP (SVG?) "overlay" operation. Are there any libraries that do this already? If there isn't a library, how to I convert the SVG spec to NumPy? The overlay compositing is defined as:

```
if 2 × Dc <= 1
  f(Sc,Dc) = 2 × Sc × Dc
otherwise
  f(Sc,Dc) = 1 - 2 × (1 - Dc) × (1 - Sc)
X        = 1
Y        = 1
Z        = 1

if 2 × Dca <= Da
  Dca' = 2 × Sca × Dca + Sca × (1 - Da) + Dca × (1 - Sa)
otherwise
  Dca' = Sa × Da - 2 × (Da - Dca) × (Sa - Sca) + Sca × (1 - Da) + Dca × (1 - Sa)
       = Sca × (1 + Da) + Dca × (1 + Sa) - 2 × Dca × Sca - Da × Sa

Da' = Sa + Da - Sa × Da
```

Admittedly, I am having trouble decoding the SVG notation. (Why two `=` statements in the 2nd otherwise?)

Comment: I don't understand your `code` above and don't even recognise the language, so can we discuss what you are trying to do in simpler terms please? You have a Numpy array, created/modified somehow by **OpenCV** and it represents a rasterised image, yes? Now you want to do something like create an SVG overlay using some other package/tool/library and you want to blend it onto the Numpy array? If so, can you give a sample Numpy array and an SVG and say how the overlaid result should look please? Also, do you need lots of blending modes, or just *"overlay"*?

Comment: You need to do 1) rasterize the SVG (convert to bitmap image) 2) convert image to Numpy, 3) apply the Overlay op between the two images/numpy arrays

Comment: This has nothing to do with SVG, aside from GIMP using the "overlay" operation as defined in SVG spec. GIMP uses this operation to do the pixel blending of images. I, in python/numpy, have two PNG images and just want to overlay them the same way as GIMP does in the layer blending options.

Comment: Ok, so please share the 2 input images and the expected result of overlaying. Also, please answer my question above about how many/which blending modes you need. Thank you.